# Does ember.js function.property() always succeed a function with a return statement?

Tags: ember.js

I've noticed that all the cases in ember.js the [function.property()](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Function.html#method_property) is found in a function with a return statement. Is that always true?  If not, can you give me a case where a function that doesn't have a return statement but has a .property()?

Comment: The computed property should have a return statement to set the computed value back on the property so that you can retrieve the value as normal one

Answer (score 0):

You need to see a property as a attribute. Ember doesn't make a distinction between functions and attributes. If you have a property it must return a value, since it acts like an attribute.

If you're looking not to return a value, but you want something to change based on another property, you'd use the `observable` pattern. Have a look [in the guide](http://emberjs.com/guides/object-model/observers/) for more information.